# Creation of a Content Type to Meet Required Use Case

Tags: entities, javascript, hooks, external-scripts

How do I achieve the following Use Case?

**Use Case Example**
Widgets, Inc. offers franchising opportunities. They have 3 different franchising levels (bronze, silver and gold).

Widgets, Inc. needs to create a Incident Report(Add New Content) any time an associated franchise has a problem.

They need 3 different types of Incident Reports(Content Types).

1. Bronze Incident Report
2. Silver Incident Report
3. Gold Incident Report

Each Incident Report contains two elements:

1. Text field for entering report
2. A static, uneditable list of Franchises within the same tier(Bronze, Silver and Gold)

The problem is in adding the second element. I am not sure how to do this. The second element represents a secondary data source, created from an HTML or PHP page.

Comment: Do that fields you want to add have different types or are they all kind of text/longtext?

Comment: @RainerFeike You don't seem to understand my question.

Comment: Not sure why I received a negative point. This is a good question and related to Drupal development.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can clarify your question - but the -1 was not me

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify a bit more. Please read again and let me know if this helps. Thanks.

Comment: I'm speculating, but the downvote may well be because you haven't asked a question, but instead stated a list of reasonably broad requirements. That doesn't usually suit Q+A, where smaller, more specific and objectively answerable questions are preferred. Plus asking a specific question is kind of a requirement, hopefully for obvious reasons in Q+A. I'd advise breaking the task down into smaller pieces, and attacking each of those separately. That'll probably give you questions that are better suited for the format here.

Comment: @Clive The question was there, it was just implied. I have updated to explicitly define what I am asking for.

Comment: It's always better to be explicit, less room for potential ambiguity that way. I'd still recommend breaking this down into smaller parts, though. You're more likely to get answers that way, people might be put off answering by not knowing where to start to explain all the things that would need to happen for you to achieve this. I certainly am :) Not for lack of wanting to help, but I literally don't have time to write the sort of tutorial that you'd need. Others are probably in a similar position. If you ask smaller questions, the surface area for answers increases greatly

Comment: I actually thought there would be a simple answer for this one. I did not realize that an answer such as this would be so involved.

Wordpress development is easy. I would simply create a new PHP file and then add it to the configuration file.

Comment: It is, at least to me, still not clear, what you actually want to achieve. Programmatically add fields and fill them from an external source? (And so save said data in the Drupal DB?) Or just render data from an external source/api additionally to standard node fields? When/how is the user supposed to select what he wants to import and from where? This is all very vague.

Comment: Yes, programmatically add fields and fill them from an external source. The user will be able to add/edit/update fields as they would normally. 

The new content type would include an uneditable reference to a specific data.

Going to update the question to further define.

Comment: "includes data imported from PHP, JavaScript or HTML." this is hard to understand what you're getting at. To me it means one of two things a) How do I embed PHP, JavaScript or HTML in a field or b) How do I import content using a migration, RSS, Restful interface or import interface into node content?

Comment: Look at the use case example I have added. That is what I need to accomplish.

Comment: I have completely removed references to how I think it could be done. I have only defined specific use case.

Comment: Much clearer now. In what form do you have the franchise data? A content type on your site with some select option to determine what level (bronze, silver, gold) they are? Some external source?

Comment: It is an external source of data that imports data by way of a PHP, JavaScript or HTML file. Normal fields within Content Types do not work. I have found the answer to my question. https://www.drupal.org/project/iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: https://www.drupal.org/project/iframe

"A custom field, which lets you add a complete iframe to your content types; including Src-URL, setting width and height, optionally a title above, and optionally a target attribute."

This gives a user the ability to import data from a secondary source.